# Delete kth element in a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to write a code for deleting kth element in a linked list. I am unable to understand what is the error here. I would really appreciate if I someone explains the mistake.

```
            /*
    Write a method delete() that takes an int argument k and deletes the kth element in a linked list if it exists.

    */
    class Deletenode
    {
        private int N;

        private class Node
        {
            String item;
            Node next;
        }

        // Building a Linked List

        Deletenode()
        {
        Node first  = new Node();
        Node second = new Node();
        Node third  = new Node();
        Node fourth = new Node();
        Node fifth  = new Node();
        Node sixth  = new Node();

        first.item  = "to";
        second.item = "be";
        third.item  = "or";
        fourth.item = "not";
        fifth.item  = "to";
        sixth.item  = "be";

        first.next = second;
        second.next = third;
        third.next = fourth;
        fourth.next = fifth;
        fifth.next = sixth;
        sixth.next = null;
    }

        public void delete(int k)
        {
            int i = 1;
            for(Node x = first; x!= null || i== --k; x = x.next,i++)
            {
                if(i == k-1)
                x = x.next.next;
            }

        }

        public void show()
        {
            for(Node x = first; x!= null; x = x.next)
            {
                System.out.print(x.item);
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Deletenode d = new Deletenode();
            d.show();
            d.delete(3);
            d.show();

        }


    }
```

The errors I am getting are

```
            deleteknode.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
            for(Node x = first; x!= null || i== --k; x = x.next,i++)
                         ^
      symbol:   variable first
      location: class Deletenode
    deleteknode.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
            for(Node x = first; x!= null; x = x.next)
                         ^
      symbol:   variable first
      location: class Deletenode
    2 errors
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you defined the Item class?

Comment: You most likely intend for Item to be a String instead of an Item type for the way you use it.  Also see Sotirios's answer below

Comment: Item is a type parameter ... I am not sure I need to define it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put code like that directly in the body of a class.

```
first.item  = "to";
second.item = "be";
third.item  = "or";
fourth.item = "not";
fifth.item  = "to";
sixth.item  = "be";

first.next = second;
second.next = third;
third.next = fourth;
fourth.next = fifth;
fifth.next = sixth;
sixth.next = null;
```

Move it to an instance initializer, constructor, or method and invoke it.

---

Also, you've declared a type parameter for your class, `Item`. It is unbounded, so you can't just assign `String` values to elements declared with that generic type.

---

Also, this

```
 if(x == k-1)
```

doesn't make sense since `x` is an `Item` and `k-1` resolves to an `int` value.  You can't compare the two. You probably meant to count how many nodes you've iterated over.

Comment: I updated code... when i moved the code to a constructor I am unable to get reference for first. How can I solve this ?

Comment: @shbolise Add an instance field to your class to hold the `first` element.

Comment: Thanks but i am bit confused to do that... can you help me out by giving little code snippet. Thanks !

Comment: @shbolise Your field `N` is an instance field. That means it belongs to the instance, each instance will have its own copy. Create another instance field `first` of type `Node` and initialize it in your constructor. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/) is the Java tutorial on classes and objects.